# Google Sheets - Auto update table and auto add new data entries

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a table in wich raw data is entered manually, with info about clients and the requests they made.

[image]

And then I have this table in which I'm trying to analyze a bit the raw data (# of requests per client, time consumed, etc).

[image]

I need that in the last column (highlighte in yellow) to have the **Type of document most type requested by Name**, but I don't know how, what I have is the type of document most requested from ALL toghether, by using this formula:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(D$4:D$14,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(D$4:D$14,D$4:D$14)),COUNTIF(D$4:D$14,D$4:D$14),0)))

Also I need the analysis table to auto update each time a new entry is made in the raw data table.

Any help?

This is the sheet I'm using for testing:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L5YDB-iPyLKgQwTYGJjZcjrOzpkM8fMMzMudJV-ukAA/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In N3 I entered this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula({query(query({A3:D,value(B3:B)}, "select Col1, sum(Col5), count(Col4), sum(Col3) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 format sum(Col5) 'h:mm:ss'"),"select* offset 1",0), vlookup(query(query(query(A4:D, "select D, A, sum(C) group by A, D"), "select max(Col3), Col2 group by Col2 label max(Col3)''"), "select Col1")&unique(sort(filter(A4:A, len(A4:A)))), {query(query(A4:D, "select sum(C), A, D  group by A, D"), "select Col1",0)&query(query(A4:D, "select sum(C), A, D group by A, D"), "select Col2",0),query(query(A4:D, "select sum(C), A, D  group by A, D"), "select  Col3",0)}, 2, 0)})
```

that seems to output the table you had as the expected output. Maybe someone comes up with something a little shorter (lol) but untill then.. make sure to test it thoroughly...

Comment: That's insane !!

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, it is.. and I apologize to the OP for the length of the formula.. guess there's no way back from the query() road... :-)